# Can not configure compiler and build kit for Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, msvc12

I just have installed on a clean windows 10, visual studio 2015 and Qt Creator 5.5...I have some source code that depend on some libraries (lib) files which I believe were compiled using msvc2012.

The Qt can not compile my project and always complains that selected compiler can not compile for Qt 5.5...I have spent hours on this but still no success...Would someone kindly tell me what should I do? Here is some photos of my Qt build options:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual C++ doesn't maintain binaries compatibility between versions, this means that you'll need to use the same Visual Studio version with all the libraries that are exposing C++ functionality (libraries that expose only a *C* interface can be used with different compiler version).

So you have 2 options:

1) install and use Visual Studio 2012, download and install a Qt version that is built with Visual Studio 2012 (*Qt 5.5.0 for Windows 32-bit (**VS 2012**, 587 MB)* ) Note that for VS 2012 there are only 32bit binaries available (if you want x64 you need to build Qt yourself)

or
2) if you want to use Visual Studio 2015, you'll need build Qt yourself with Visual Studio 2015, since there are no already built Qt binaries for Visual Studio 2015. And depending on how the other library is written you might need to also build that with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thanks, installing VS2012 and using its compiler fixed the problem!