# Setting up Qt5 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt5, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Searching Google for 'Qt5 - Windows 10 - VS 2015' only brought up a blog post from April stating that support for VS 2015 is in the works ([link](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/04/29/windows-10-support-in-qt/)).

The Qt5 downloads page (OpenSource version) currently has no links for Visual Studio 2015. So, is it possible to use Qt5 in VS 2015, or do I just have until something new comes up?

PS. I just want to avoid installing VS2013 on top of VS2015. I can build from source should it be needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just build it from source. Next update of Qt will contain a build for 2015 msvc.

Comment: For those arriving to this post in 2016 after Qt's added 2015 support:  1. Download/Install Visual Studio 2015.  If you already have it and it's expired, sign in with a good 'ol MSN/Hotmail account to activate the community version. 2. Start a new Visual C++ project, which will provide a link to install the MSVC compiler.  3. The setup utility will ask to close Visual Studio to install some items.  Follow the on-screen instructions and then 4. Restart Qt; should be happy.   Also, dated but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897847/can-not-configure-compiler-and-build-kit-for-qt-5-5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just wrote [a small article explaining how to compile Qt 5.5.1 (with QtWebkit) with Visual Studio 2015](https://pempek.net/articles/2015/10/18/compiling-qt-5-5-1-with-visual-studio-2015/).

I realize this is by no mean a good answer: while it does the job, that article mostly relies on helper Windows batch files you can download from my site. As a consequence, while I don't plan to pull my site or the article itself, other SO users or admins would be in their right to flag this answer as too volatile...

Anyways, until Qt folks offer official pre-built binaries built with Visual Studio 2015, I believe my article saves the day. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for this, even though a lot of time has passed since I asked the question, I never really found a solution.

Comment: Greg, thanks for your post. It pointed me in the right direction. I'm not very experienced building C++ libraries like this from scratch, and things always seem to go wrong. I can't figure out why the QT Team hasn't hosted a pre-compiled binary for VS2015 yet. It's rather frustrating.

Regarding your bat file, I let it run overnight and it worked. However, nmake install wasn't executed so there appears to be something wrong when changing directories.

Comment: If `nmake install` wasn't executed it means `nmake` failed and something didn't compile correctly

Comment: Nice and comprehensive article. Can you please save us the process and place the built libraries somewhere for download?

Comment: I'm sorry I won't host Qt prebuilt binaries for different reasons:

1. I don't have a proper hosting plan for that task (it weights 3.34GB for both 32 and 64bit builds)
2. it's prebuilt with my own view of which configuration settings should be applied
3. it's a rather bad idea to blindly download non official binaries from the internet

Comment: Thanks for the article and the handy script. To get the script working I did have to add the ICU libs explicitly:  _-L %ICU_DIST%\lib -I %ICU_DIST%\include_ at the line (line 52  in the x64 script) with the call to configure. Without that there were unresolved ICU symbols. This was needed even though the script includes a SET LIB=%LIB%;%ICU_DIST%\lib at line 35.

Answer (score 3):

[Qt5.6.0 Beta](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/12/18/qt-5-6-beta-released/) includes a prebuilt image for Visual Studio 2015. However, the Qt Visual Studio add-in is no longer supported. There's an extension called [Qt5Package](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c89ff880-8509-47a4-a262-e4fa07168408) you can install instead.

I found when I tried to add Qt 5.6.0 Beta in the extension I got the error  "This Qt version uses an unsupported makefile generator (used: MSVC.NETMSBUILD, supported: MSVC.NET, MSBUILD)". The workaround is in C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf Qt 5.6.0 splits all the version-specific changes into a separate file msvc-base.conf. If you copy the contents of this file and replace the line "include(msvc- base.conf)" in mscv-desktop.conf then Qt5Package recognises the Qt 5.6.0 Beta with no problems.

Note this still needs to be fixed in Qt5Package.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me out of the box. I had no issues adding Qt 5.6.0 beta.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But I've just found the magic key. The package in the following link has almost exactly the behavior of Qt Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.4 for Qt5. It includes everything needed to complete the work with Qt:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c89ff880-8509-47a4-a262-e4fa07168408

Answer (score 0):

## Building Qt

1. *Call* the vcvarsall batch with the correct architecture, e.g.:

`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64`

2. *Call* the Qt environment batch, e.g.,

`call C:\Qt\x64\vs2015\qt561-1_x64\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin\qtenv2.bat`

3. If using `jom`, add `jom` to path, e.g.,

`Set PATH=C:\Qt\x64\vs2015\qt561-1_x64\Tools\QtCreator\bin;%PATH%`

4. Set your Qt Makespec, e.g.,

`Set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2015`

5. Change directories to the source you want to build against, e.g.,

`cd C:\Qt\x64\vs2015\qt561-1_x64\5.6\Src\qtbase`

6. Run `configure` with whatever options you may need, e.g.,

`configure -platform win32-msvc2015 -nomake tests -nomake examples`

Add `-opensource` to your `configure` command if building open source Qt.

7. Run `nmake` or `jom -j %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` or replace `%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` with the number of threads you want to utilize.

## Integrating Qt

Take the contents of this code block and save it into a file called `qt.natvis` and place if here like this, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\qt.natvis`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
<Type Name="QPoint">
    <AlternativeType Name="QPointF"/>
    <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
        <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QRect">
    <DisplayString>{{ x = {x1}, y = {y1}, width = {x2 - x1 + 1}, height = {y2 - y1 + 1} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[x]">x1</Item>
        <Item Name="[y]">y1</Item>
        <Item Name="[width]">x2 - x1 + 1</Item>
        <Item Name="[height]">y2 - y1 + 1</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QRectF">
    <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp}, width = {w}, height = {h} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
        <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
        <Item Name="[width]">w</Item>
        <Item Name="[height]">h</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QSize">
    <AlternativeType Name="QSizeF"/>
    <DisplayString>{{ width = {wd}, height = {ht} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[width]">wd</Item>
        <Item Name="[height]">ht</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QLine">
    <AlternativeType Name="QLineF"/>
    <DisplayString>{{ start point = {pt1}, end point = {pt2} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Synthetic Name="[start point]">
            <DisplayString>{pt1}</DisplayString>
            <Expand>
                <ExpandedItem>pt1</ExpandedItem>
            </Expand>
        </Synthetic>
        <Synthetic Name="[end point]">
            <DisplayString>{pt2}</DisplayString>
            <Expand>
                <ExpandedItem>pt2</ExpandedItem>
            </Expand>
        </Synthetic>

    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QPolygon">
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>(QPoint*)((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset)</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QPolygonF">
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[closed]">
            d-&gt;size &gt; 0
                &amp;&amp; ((((QPointF*)((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset)[0]).xp
            == (((QPointF*)((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset)[d-&gt;size - 1]).xp)
                &amp;&amp; ((((QPointF*)((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset)[0]).yp
            == (((QPointF*)((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset)[d-&gt;size - 1]).yp)
        </Item>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>(QPointF*)((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset)</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name ="QVector2D">
    <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
        <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name ="QVector3D">
    <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp}, z = {zp} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
        <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
        <Item Name="[z]">zp</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name ="QVector4D">
    <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp}, z = {zp}, w = {wp} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
        <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
        <Item Name="[z]">zp</Item>
        <Item Name="[w]">wp</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name ="QMatrix">
    <DisplayString>
        {{ m11 = {_m11}, m12 = {_m12}, m21 = {_m21}, m22 = {_m22}, ... }}
    </DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[m11]">_m11</Item>
        <Item Name="[m12]">_m12</Item>
        <Item Name="[m21]">_m21</Item>
        <Item Name="[m22]">_m22</Item>
        <Item Name="[dx]">_dx</Item>
        <Item Name="[dy]">_dy</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name ="QMatrix4x4">
    <DisplayString>
        {{ m11 = {m[0][0]}, m12 = {m[1][0]}, m13 = {m[2][0]}, m14 = {m[3][0]}, ... }}
    </DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[m11]">m[0][0]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m12]">m[1][0]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m13]">m[2][0]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m14]">m[3][0]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m21]">m[0][1]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m22]">m[1][1]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m23]">m[2][1]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m24]">m[3][1]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m31]">m[0][2]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m32]">m[1][2]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m33]">m[2][2]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m34]">m[3][2]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m41]">m[0][3]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m42]">m[1][3]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m43]">m[2][3]</Item>
        <Item Name="[m44]">m[3][3]</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QSizePolicy">
    <DisplayString>
        {{ horizontal = {static_cast&lt;Policy&gt;(bits.horPolicy)}, vertical = {static_cast&lt;Policy&gt;(bits.verPolicy)}, type = {ControlType(1 &lt;&lt; bits.ctype)} }}
    </DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Synthetic Name="[vertical policy]">
            <DisplayString>QSizePolicy::Policy::{static_cast&lt;Policy&gt;(bits.verPolicy)}</DisplayString>
        </Synthetic>
        <Synthetic Name="[horizontal policy]">
            <DisplayString>QSizePolicy::Policy::{static_cast&lt;Policy&gt;(bits.horPolicy)}</DisplayString>
        </Synthetic>
        <Synthetic Name="[control type]">
            <DisplayString>QSizePolicy::ControlType::{ControlType(1 &lt;&lt; bits.ctype)}</DisplayString>
        </Synthetic>
        <Synthetic Name="[expanding directions]">
            <DisplayString
                Condition="(static_cast&lt;Policy&gt;(bits.verPolicy) &amp; ExpandFlag)">
                    Qt::Vertical (2)
                </DisplayString>
            <DisplayString
                Condition="(static_cast&lt;Policy&gt;(bits.horPolicy) &amp; ExpandFlag)">
                    Qt::Horizontal (1)
            </DisplayString>
        </Synthetic>
        <Item Name="[vertical stretch]">static_cast&lt;int&gt;(bits.verStretch)</Item>
        <Item Name="[horizontal stretch]">static_cast&lt;int&gt;(bits.horStretch)</Item>
        <Item Name="[has height for width]">bits.hfw == 1</Item>
        <Item Name="[has width for height]">bits.wfh == 1</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QChar">
    <DisplayString>{ucs,c}</DisplayString>
    <StringView>ucs,c</StringView>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[latin 1]">ucs > 0xff ? '\0' : char(ucs),c</Item>
        <Item Name="[unicode]">ucs,c</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QString">
    <DisplayString>{((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub}</DisplayString>
    <StringView>((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub</StringView>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">d-&gt;size</Item>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),c</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QByteArray">
    <DisplayString>{((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset),sb}</DisplayString>
    <StringView>((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset),sb</StringView>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">d-&gt;size</Item>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset),c</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QBitArray">
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {(d.d-&gt;size &lt;&lt; 3) - *((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d.d)) + d.d-&gt;offset)} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d.d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <IndexListItems>
            <Size>(d.d-&gt;size &lt;&lt; 3) - *((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d.d)) + d.d-&gt;offset)</Size>
            <ValueNode>
                (*(reinterpret_cast&lt;const unsigned char*&gt;((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d.d)) + d.d-&gt;offset) + 1
                    + ($i &gt;&gt; 3)) &amp; (1 &lt;&lt; ($i &amp; 7))) != 0
            </ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QVarLengthArray&lt;*&gt;">
    <AlternativeType Name="QVarLengthArray&lt;*, int&gt;"/>
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {s} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[capacity]">a</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>s</Size>
            <ValuePointer>ptr</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QDate">
    <DisplayString>{{ julian day = {jd} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand></Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QTime">
    <DisplayString
        Condition="mds == 1">{{ millisecond = {mds} }}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString
        Condition="mds != 1">{{ milliseconds = {mds} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[hour]"
              Condition="(mds / 3600000) == 1">mds / 3600000, d</Item>
        <Item Name="[hours]"
              Condition="(mds / 3600000) != 1">mds / 3600000, d</Item>
        <Item Name="[minute]"
              Condition="((mds % 3600000) / 60000) == 1">(mds % 3600000) / 60000, d</Item>
        <Item Name="[minutes]"
              Condition="((mds % 3600000) / 60000) != 1">(mds % 3600000) / 60000, d</Item>
        <Item Name="[second]"
              Condition="((mds / 1000) % 60) == 1">(mds / 1000) % 60, d</Item>
        <Item Name="[seconds]"
              Condition="((mds / 1000) % 60) != 1">(mds / 1000) % 60, d</Item>
        <Item Name="[millisecond]"
              Condition="(mds % 1000) == 1">mds % 1000, d</Item>
        <Item Name="[milliseconds]"
              Condition="(mds % 1000) != 1">mds % 1000, d</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QRegularExpression">
    <DisplayString>{d.pattern}</DisplayString>
</Type>

<Type Name="QSharedData">
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">ref._q_value</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QSharedPointer&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>strong reference to shared pointer of type {"$T1"}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[is null]">value == 0</Item>
        <Item Name="[weak referenced]">d-&gt;weakref._q_value</Item>
        <Item Name="[strong referenced]">d-&gt;strongref._q_value</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QSharedDataPointer&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>pointer to implicit shared object of type {"$T1"}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <ExpandedItem>d</ExpandedItem>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QExplicitlySharedDataPointer&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>pointer to explicit shared object of type {"$T1"}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <ExpandedItem>d</ExpandedItem>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QPointer&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>guarded pointer to subclass of QObject of type {"$T1"}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[is null]">wp.d == 0 || wp.d-&gt;strongref._q_value == 0 || wp.value == 0</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QWeakPointer&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>weak reference to shared pointer of type {"$T1"}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[is null]">d == 0 || d-&gt;strongref._q_value == 0 || value == 0</Item>
        <Item Name="[weak referenced]">d-&gt;weakref._q_value</Item>
        <Item Name="[strong referenced]">d-&gt;strongref._q_value</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QScopedPointer&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>scoped pointer to a dynamically allocated object of type {"$T1"}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[is null]">!d</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QScopedArrayPointer&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>scoped pointer to dynamically allocated array of objects of type {"$T1"}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[is null]">!d</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QPair&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>({first}, {second})</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[first]">first</Item>
        <Item Name="[second]">second</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QVector&lt;*&gt;">
    <AlternativeType Name="QStack&lt;*&gt;"></AlternativeType>
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>($T1*)((reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)) + d-&gt;offset)</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QList&lt;*&gt;">
    <AlternativeType Name="QStringList"></AlternativeType>
    <AlternativeType Name="QQueue&lt;*&gt;"></AlternativeType>
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {d-&gt;end - d-&gt;begin} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <IndexListItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;end - d-&gt;begin</Size>
            <ValueNode>*reinterpret_cast&lt;$T1*&gt;((sizeof($T1) &gt; sizeof(void*))
                ? reinterpret_cast&lt;Node*&gt;(d->array + d->begin + $i)->v
                : reinterpret_cast&lt;$T1*&gt;(d->array + d->begin + $i))
            </ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QLinkedList&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <LinkedListItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <HeadPointer>d-&gt;n</HeadPointer>
            <NextPointer>n</NextPointer>
            <ValueNode>(*(QLinkedListNode&lt;$T1&gt;*)this).t</ValueNode>
        </LinkedListItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QMapNode&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>({key}, {value})</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[key]">key</Item>
        <Item Name="[value]">value</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QMap&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <AlternativeType Name="QMultiMap&lt;*,*&gt;"/>
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <TreeItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <HeadPointer>d-&gt;header.left</HeadPointer>
            <LeftPointer>left</LeftPointer>
            <RightPointer>right</RightPointer>
            <ValueNode>*((QMapNode&lt;$T1,$T2&gt;*)this)</ValueNode>
        </TreeItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QHashNode&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="next == 0">(empty)</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="next != 0">({key}, {value})</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[key]" Condition="next != 0">key</Item>
        <Item Name="[value]" Condition="next != 0">value</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QHash&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <AlternativeType Name="QMultiHash&lt;*,*&gt;"/>
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <IndexListItems>
            <Size>d-&gt;numBuckets</Size>
            <ValueNode>*((QHashNode&lt;$T1,$T2&gt;*)d-&gt;buckets[$i])</ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QHashNode&lt;*,QHashDummyValue&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="next == 0">(empty)</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="next != 0">({key})</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[key]" Condition="next != 0">key</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QSet&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {q_hash.d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <ExpandedItem>q_hash</ExpandedItem>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QCache&lt;*,*&gt;::Node">
    <DisplayString>({*keyPtr}, {*t})</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[key]">*keyPtr</Item>
        <Item Name="[value]">*t</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QCache&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {hash.d-&gt;size} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[max coast]">mx</Item>
        <Item Name="[total coast]">total</Item>
        <Item Name="[referenced]">hash.d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <LinkedListItems>
            <Size>hash.d-&gt;size</Size>
            <HeadPointer>f</HeadPointer>
            <NextPointer>n</NextPointer>
            <ValueNode>*((Node*)this)</ValueNode>
        </LinkedListItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QVariant">
    <!--Region DisplayString QVariant-->

    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::UnknownType">Invalid</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::Bool">{d.data.b}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::Int">{d.data.i}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::UInt">{d.data.u}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::LongLong">{d.data.ll}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::ULongLong">{d.data.ull}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::Double">{d.data.d}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QChar">{d.data.c}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QVariantMap">
        {*((QMap&lt;QString,QVariant&gt;*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QVariantList">
        {*((QList&lt;QVariant&gt;*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QString">
        {*((QString*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QStringList">
        {*((QStringList*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QByteArray">
        {*((QByteArray*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QBitArray">
        {*((QBitArray*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QDate">
        {*((QDate*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QTime">
        {*((QTime*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QDateTime">DateTime</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QUrl">Url</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QLocale">Locale</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QRect">
        {*((QRect*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QRectF">
        {*((QRectF*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QSize">
        {*((QSize*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QSizeF">
        {*((QSizeF*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QLine">
        {*((QLine*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QLineF">
        {*((QLineF*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QPoint">
        {*((QPoint*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QPointF">
        {*((QPointF*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QRegExp">RegExp</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QRegularExpression">RegularExpression</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QVariantHash">
        {*((QHash&lt;QString,QVariant&gt;*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))}
    </DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QEasingCurve">EasingCurve</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QUuid">Uuid</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QModelIndex">ModelIndex</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::LastCoreType">LastCoreType</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QFont">Font</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QPixmap">Pixmap</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QBrush">Brush</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QColor">Color</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QPalette">Palette</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QImage">Image</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QPolygon">Polygon</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QRegion">Region</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QBitmap">Bitmap</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QCursor">Cursor</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QKeySequence">KeySequence</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QPen">Pen</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QTextLength">TextLength</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QTextFormat">TextFormat</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QMatrix">Matrix</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QTransform">Transform</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QMatrix4x4">Matrix4x4</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QVector2D">Vector2D</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QVector3D">Vector3D</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QVector4D">Vector4D</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QQuaternion">Quaternion</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QPolygonF">PolygonF</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QIcon">Icon</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::LastGuiType">LastGuiType</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QSizePolicy">SizePolicy</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::User">UserType</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="d.type == 0xffffffff">LastType</DisplayString>

    <!--End region DisplayString QVariant-->

    <!--Region DisplayView QVariant-->

    <StringView Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QChar">d.data.c</StringView>

    <StringView Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QString">
        *((QString*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))
    </StringView>

    <StringView Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QByteArray">
        *((QByteArray*)(d.is_shared ? d.data.shared-&gt;ptr
            : reinterpret_cast&lt;const void *&gt;(&amp;d.data.ptr)))
    </StringView>

    <!--End region DisplayView QVariant-->

</Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

You should now have the ability to debug with Qt in Visual Studio.

### Warning

Even though Qt mentions it, they really don't emphasize how important is to properly clean if your build failed. This is [what the site says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html), and I've added my own derived notes below the quoted text:

> Note: If you later need to reconfigure and rebuild Qt from the same
>   location, ensure that all traces of the previous configuration are
>   removed by entering the build directory and typing `nmake distclean`
>   before running configure again.

1. If your configuration using `configure` needs to change at all, you've got to run `nmake distclean` or `jom -j %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% distclean`
2. If your build failed, run clean, e.g., `nmake clean` or `jom -j %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% clean`

Then you should run `configure` with whatever options you need, and then `nmake` or `jom -j %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%`.